# How the Sitecore item field values are stored in Sitecore content databases?

Tags: sql-database

How the Sitecore item field values are stored in Sitecore content databases and which table we can see the data?

Answer (score 1):

The table name is [Fields]. Where you can fine the Item ID, FieldId and Value.

Here is the query.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [Id]
      ,[ItemId]
      ,[Language]
      ,[FieldId]
      ,[Value]
      ,[Created]
      ,[Updated]
  FROM [10.3.1.dev.local_Master].[dbo].[Fields] where ItemId = '4048330F-6389-4A6C-B7F8-A6492BFA21E1
```

'

[image]

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Data in Sitecore is not always stored the same way it is displayed.

Sitecore uses SQL Server to store most of its content. While content authors will see formatted text and structured content in the Content Editor and Experience Editor, Sitecore stores all data in a raw form in its database tables. Some raw values match their display value - for example, content based on the Single-Line Text data type. Most data, however, is transformed into custom XML or a direct reference to other Sitecore items.

Getting item's field value depends on its type of field means it is Versioned, Unversioned or SharedField. Each type of field and its values are stored in different table. So, before getting any field's value, it is good to know its field type and based on it we can get execute query.

See how below function helps to return a shared field's value of an item, similarly we can write function for Versioned and Unversioned fields too:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SC_GetSharedFieldValue] 
(
 @ItemID [uniqueidentifier],
 @FieldID  [uniqueidentifier]
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @Result  nvarchar(max)
 SELECT @Result = value 
  FROM [dbo].[sharedFields]
  where ItemId=@ItemID
  and fieldid=@FieldID
 RETURN @Result
END
```

Here, **Size field's ID is:{6954B7C7-2487-423F-8600-436CB3B6DC0E}**. So, for getting media item's size, we can use above function as below. Here, quert list down all child media media of **/sitecore/media library/Images/Banners** and its **ID is: {1D02B586-0B55-4C2F-AED4-A3172B81B0DA}**

```
SELECT ID, [Name], [dbo].[SC_GetSharedFieldValue] (ID, '{6954B7C7-2487-423F-8600-436CB3B6DC0E}') AS FileSize
 FROM [dbo].[Items]
 WHERE [ParentID] = '{1D02B586-0B55-4C2F-AED4-A3172B81B0DA}'
```

Reference: [Sitecore - Get items details using Database Query](https://sitecoreblog.patelyogesh.in/2013/08/sitecore-get-items-details-using.html)

Hope it helps!